# Tkinter canvas doesn't show my "player" symbol

Tags: python, tkinter

I am beginner in Python and want just to make a red square that will move by pressed keys on keyboard. But after I had run this, only green canvas showed up, no red square. Here is the code:

Imports:

```
try:
 import Tkinter
except:
 import tkinter as Tkinter

import time
```

Here just some constants

```
__author__ = "Brano"

print(__author__)

GAME_WIDTH = 800
GAME_HEIGHT = 600
GAME_BG = 'green'
MOVE_SPEED = 10
```

Main class with initialization:

```
class Game(Tkinter.Tk):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    # Trigger Of Other Functions 
    self.x = GAME_WIDTH/2
    self.y = GAME_HEIGHT/2
    self.create_board()
    self.create_men()
    self.bind('<Any-KeyPress>',self.move)
```

Creating board:

```
  def create_board(self):
    self.board = Tkinter.Canvas(width=GAME_WIDTH, height=GAME_HEIGHT, 
bg=GAME_BG)
    self.board.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    return
```

Creating red square:

```
def create_men(self):
    self.men = self.board.create_rectangle(300, 300, 310, 310, fill='red')
    return
```

Move square after pressing keys:

```
def move(self, event=None):
    key = event.keysym
    if key=='Left':
        self.x = MOVE_SPEED
    elif key=='Right':
        self.x = -MOVE_SPEED
    elif key=='Up':
        self.y = MOVE_SPEED
    elif key=='Down':
        self.y = -MOVE_SPEED
    else:
        pass
    return
```

Just tkinter updates:

```
def TkUpdate(self):
    self.update()
    self.update_idletasks()
    return
```

My main move update:

```
def GameUpdate(self):
    self.board.move(self.men, self.x, self.y)
    return
```

Checking if it is imported:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 root=Game(className=" Snake Game ")
 while True:
  root.TkUpdate()
  root.GameUpdate()
  time.sleep(0.09)

else :
 print("U cannot import me !")
```

[Here is the canvas I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMo85.png)

Here is the whole class:

```
class Game(Tkinter.Tk):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    # Trigger Of Other Functions 
    self.x = GAME_WIDTH/2
    self.y = GAME_HEIGHT/2
    self.create_board()
    self.create_men()
    self.bind('<Any-KeyPress>',self.move)

def create_board(self):
    self.board = Tkinter.Canvas(width=GAME_WIDTH, height=GAME_HEIGHT, bg=GAME_BG)
    self.board.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    return


def create_men(self):
    self.men = self.board.create_rectangle(300, 300, 310, 310, fill='red')
    return

def move(self, event=None):
    key = event.keysym
    if key=='Left':
        self.x = MOVE_SPEED
    elif key=='Right':
        self.x = -MOVE_SPEED
    elif key=='Up':
        self.y = MOVE_SPEED
    elif key=='Down':
        self.y = -MOVE_SPEED
    else:
        pass
    return

def TkUpdate(self):
    self.update()
    self.update_idletasks()
    return

def GameUpdate(self):
    self.board.move(self.men, self.x, self.y)
    return
```

Comment: Can we have a version of your code that's not split into fifty tiny fragments, please?

Comment: Here you have it now

Comment: Please read and follow the advice about how to create a [mcve], and remove all the duplicate code. If possible we need one single, short block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid calling `update` and `sleep`. Instead use `after` and `mainloop`. Your code should schedule your gameloop using `after` and enter the mainloop after setting up everything. Then keep scheduling the gameloop with `after` calls.

Your actual problem is you have confused using self.x and self.y as a position in the setup but then use these as a relative move in the game loop. So when you first call `GameUpdate` you move the rectangle by half the canvas size and it immediately moves out of view. Below is a version that uses these as the 'man' position and asserts the position using `coords` each time around the game loop.

```
import tkinter as tk

GAME_WIDTH = 800
GAME_HEIGHT = 600
GAME_BG = 'green'
MOVE_SPEED = 10
MAN_SIZE = 20

class Game(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # Trigger Of Other Functions 
        self.x = GAME_WIDTH/2
        self.y = GAME_HEIGHT/2
        self.create_board()
        self.create_men()
        self.bind('<Any-KeyPress>',self.move)

    def create_board(self):
        self.board = tk.Canvas(width=GAME_WIDTH, height=GAME_HEIGHT, bg=GAME_BG)
        self.board.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def create_men(self):
        self.men = self.board.create_rectangle((self.x, self.y, self.x + MAN_SIZE, self.y + MAN_SIZE), fill='red', outline='black')

    def move(self, event=None):
        key = event.keysym
        print(key)
        if key=='Left':
            self.x = self.x - MOVE_SPEED
        elif key=='Right':
            self.x = self.x + MOVE_SPEED
        elif key=='Up':
            self.y = self.y - MOVE_SPEED
        elif key=='Down':
            self.y = self.y + MOVE_SPEED
        else:
            pass
        return

    def game_loop(self):
        self.board.coords(self.men, (self.x, self.y, self.x + MAN_SIZE, self.y + MAN_SIZE))
        self.after(10, self.game_loop)

def main():
    game = Game(className="Snake")
    game.after(10, game.game_loop)
    game.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```